# What does $U_i$ mean in $U_iA_i \in \mathcal{F}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

I am a fourth-year math student, so I understand that $\cup$ means union of sets. However, I got stuck reading *Probability: Theory and Examples by Durrett*. Considering that I don't know what $\cup_i$ means, can someone please recommend me what field to read about to understand this textbook?

Comment: $i$ is an index variable for the sets $A_i$.   For example, if $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then $\cup_i A_i=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5$.  Similarly $\Sigma_i x_i=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5$

Comment: Oh... so $\cup_iA_i$ means union of all sets $A_i$? In other words, $\cup_iA_i = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$?

Comment: Yes, it means union of all sets $A_i$.  It should be made clear in the context whether $i$ ranges over a finite set or an infinite set

Comment: Thanks! I also see in the book this: $\cap_iA_i = (\cup_i A^c_i)^c$. What field/textbook of Mathematics can I see the proof?

Comment: Set theory (DeMorgan’s law)

Answer (score 1):

$\cup_i A_i$ indicates the union of all sets $A_i$.  $i$ is an index variable for the sets $A_i$.  It should be made clear in the context whether $i$ ranges over a finite set or an infinite set.  For example, if $i\in\{1,2,\dots n\}$, then $\cup_i A_i=A_1\cup A_2 \cup\dots\cup A_n$.  You could read about this and more in a textbook of elementary set theory.